# How to maintain state of the array when switching between the screens?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UITableView and have it so when you press the first cell, it takes you to a new table by reloading a data. When you press the second cell, you go to another table  and so on. While coming back i want to maintain previous state of the table view .For this i have maintained one parent variable .When i select any element form the table then i store this element into the parent element and on that basic i am reloading the table while i coming back. Its working,But this became very lengthy logic ? And i sense that it is hitting cleanness of the program . Is there any better optimized way to maintain state of the array  when switching between the screens?

Comment: Why dont u create secondTableViewController and when you click on any cell in parentViewController you can navigate to the secondTableViewController also passing the data with which you want to  populate the table

Comment: @aj.:but we can't decide the depth of the table .

Comment: What depth are you talking about? create different view controller - parentViewController and SecondViewController
 (1)ParentViewController with the table which is populated by the parent variable is shown
 (2)SecondViewCOntroller with the table which is populated by the data you pass that you want to show
---So when you click on the first cell or either cell on your parentVIewController you can pushViewCOntroller to the secondViewController(pass the data you want to display there)... then finally when you want to go back to you main view(ParentViewController) you simply popViewController

Comment: @aj.:Suppose if i have data structure like tree. I it can any numbers of node and can be change. So i will have table equal to number of nodes in that tree then how can you done that with two navigation controllers.

Comment: if i understood correct... you have a parent table view and when u click that particular cell you want the cell to expands with something like innercell/subcells....?

Answer (score 0):

Use the table views in a UINavigationController stack.

Comment: @VXtreme Just google. Any basic UINavigationController tutorial will get you up to speed.

Comment: :I have googled a lot.But how is there any way to add a uiview to UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

Add one gobal mutableArray or use NSUserdefault to save current index of all tableview. By default it will be 0 for all tableview.

Now tableview have didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method where u change value everytime when new index selected.

In view will appear of all tableview

```
-(void)viewwillappear
{
 [tableview reloadData];
}
```

Make sure in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of all tableview current index should be selected

Comment: i am same thing by using the object at selected index.